# Update is not woking in node js for postman

Tags: reactjs, api, mongoose, postman

```
router.put("/update/:username", update);

function update(req, res, next) {
  userService
    .update(req.params.username, req.body)
    .then(() => res.json({}))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
}

async function update(username, userParam) {
  const user = await User.findById(username);
  if (!user) throw "User not found";
  Object.assign(user, { status: userParam.status });

  if (await user.save()) {
    throw 'Username "' + user.username + '" is updated';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `findById` but passing the username. You should use `findOne` instead.
Try to simplify your code like this:

```
router.put("/update/:username", update);

async function update(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username });
        if (!user) return res.status(400).send('User not found');
        user.status = req.body.status
      
        await user.save()

        res.status(201).send('User updated')
      } catch (err) {
        next(err)
      }
}
```